# Easier way to add "\n" to all output lines in Python?

Tags: python

The following script works for me, but I wonder if it could be done in an easier way.
I am using Python 2.7.3.

```
f = open('file.txt')
out = open('script.sql', "w")
for line in f:
        out.write('%s%s' % (line[:-1], '\n'))
f.close()
out.close()
```

Thanks,

Comment: wow thank you. You two are just itching to press the downvote instead of providing a useful answer.

Comment: `with open('file.txt') as f, open('script.sql', 'w') as out:` newline indent `for line in f: out.write(...)` is cleaner and more compact

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there's `line[:-1] + '\n'`.

Answer (score 3):

don't use the old `%s` string formatting use `format()`

```
   out.write('{0}{1}'.format(line[:-1], '\n'))
```

or  `out.write('{0}\n'.format(line[:-1]))`

Answer (score 3):

You can either just add a `\n` by using `line[:-1] + '\n'`, or you can use a simpler formatting, like `'%s\n' % (line[:-1],)`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it seems a little redundant to strip the newline and add it again:

```
f = open('file.txt')
out = open('script.sql', "w")
for line in f:
     out.write(line)
f.close()
out.close()
```

Or better, use `shutil` to copy the file directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you use print, the `\n` is added automagically:

```
print >>out, line[:-1]
```

It is suggested these days to use `with` like so:

```
with open('file.txt') as f, open('script.sql', "w") as out:
    for line in f:
       print >>out, line[:-1]

# autoclosed f and out...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `out.write(line.rstrip('\r\n') + '\n')`, to add a newline to every line without duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Before you write the contents of line out to the file, using line.rstrip like this:

`out.write(line.rstrip('\r\n') + '\n')`

will remove any existing carriage-returns or line-feeds '\r' or '\n`, and will add a newline to every line.